# MsAccess SQL Exception Too few parameters

Tags: java, sql, netbeans, ms-access-2010

Currently making a java program that grabs data off of a MSAccess Database and some of these errors are extremely frustrating. I keep getting this SQL.Exception : Too few parameters. Expected 1 error on the last remaining bugs in this program.

Little background on the db: It has 3 tables (A player table (11 columns), a team table (3 columns), and an Opponent table (6 columns).

These are both of the functions and I am fairly certain the problem lies in here somewhere

```
conn = Connect.ConnectDB();
    String sql = "insert into Player ("+"PlayerLastName,"+"PlayerFirstName,"+"Position)"+ "values("+txtid.getText()+ ",'"+txtname.getText()+"','"+txtaddress.getText()+"')" ;
    try{
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.executeQuery();
        pst.setString(1, txtid.getText());
        pst.setString(2, txtname.getText());
        pst.setString(3, txtaddress.getText());
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, txtid.getText() + " Saved");
        UpdateJTable();
        //conn.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
```

or this function

```
        String sql = "select * from Player where PlayerLastName = " +txtid.getText()+ "";
    String pine = null;
    try{
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

        ResultSet res;
        res = pst.executeQuery();

        pine.equalsIgnoreCase(jTable1.getModel().getValueAt(rowsu, 10).toString());

        while(res.next()){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, txtname + " " + txtid.getText() + " has a total of " +"4");//+ pine);//res.getInt("Penalties") );

        }
        UpdateJTable();

    }
    catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
```

Comment: This error message typically resolves to a misspelled column name.

Answer (score 1):

For one thing, it looks like you're missing single quotes around the last name in the insert statement.

There may be other errors as well, that's just the first thing I noticed.

This should be pretty easy to debug if you just log the sql string before executing it.

**EDIT**

I think your calls to setString() are also a problem.  Here is how you should do this:

```
conn = Connect.ConnectDB();
    String sql = "insert into Player (PlayerLastName, PlayerFirstName, Position) values(?, ?, ?)";
    try{
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.setString(1, txtid.getText());
        pst.setString(2, txtname.getText());
        pst.setString(3, txtaddress.getText());
        pst.execute();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, txtid.getText() + " Saved");
        UpdateJTable();
        //conn.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
```

Comment: I am very new to sql. When you say log do you mean output into the console?

Comment: FYI, it's a very bad practice to concatenate user input into a SQL statement.  Use parameters instead.  Google "SQL injection".